# Azure Linux Reset password fails with ParentResourceNotFound

Tags: linux, azure, azure-linux

I am trying to reset a password in the Azure portal for a Linux VM and I'm getting the error:  ParentResourceNotFound.  No extensions, like VMAccessForLinux, are shown as installed but I know I was able to do this in the past when there weren't any.  So I'm not sure the lack of listed extensions should be a roadblocker here.

This is ARM deployment, not ASM.
Redhat 7.8

ErrorCode: ParentResourceNotFound
Message:   Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'xxxxxxxx' not found.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question [MsDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-parent-resource?tabs=json)

Comment: No, it doesn't.  Sorry I should have mentioned that I already exhausted the basic google results.  I did find a solution, though.  I'll try to post the solution when I have some downtime.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure how this relates to a parent resource not being found, but what I did to solve my problem was this.

I tried to see if I could even load the Serial Console.  It gave an error that to run serial console boot diagnostics needed a custom storage account.  So I went to boot diagnostics -> settings -> Enable with custom storage account
-> Save.

After that the serial console would load and also the reset password feature seems to be working.